# How to use '@global' with React-JSS

Tags: reactjs, jss

I'm using React-JSS and not understanding how to use '@global' to create global styles. [The doc](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-global/?v=v10.0.3) doesn't indicate (as far as I can tell) how the global style gets feed/hooked into the React app. I created a sample app where I try feeding the global styles to the 'style' attribute of the top level component but that does not work.

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-haibt-wv4bv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Here is App.js

```js
import React from "react";

const styles = {
  "@global": {
    body: {
      color: "green"
    },
    a: {
      textDecoration: "underline"
    }
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={styles} className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation you point describes jss core api. You can look [here](https://cssinjs.org/jss-api?v=v10.0.3#create-style-sheet) on how to use it.

To use it in react-jss without dealing with jss instance you can use hooks or HOCs.

The example bellow uses hooks.

```
import React from "react";
import { createUseStyles } from "react-jss";

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  "@global": {
    body: {
      color: "green"
    },
    a: {
      textDecoration: "underline"
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think when I had an example using createUseStyles I forgot to call useStyles().